# Finding the file size of an image file in the Sony Camera Remote API

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm writing a fairly involved application for working with Sony cameras.

I can list the contents of the camera and copy image files no problem at all, but I can't seem to figure out the size of the files before I start to download them.

I'm receiving the file list using the standard `getContentList` API, and finding the files using the `originals` array in the response. That response seems to have no file size information in it.

Is this possible? Knowing the file size before downloading is important for a good user experience, and all the other camera APIs support it.

I do get the size when I start to download in the HTTP `Content-Length` header, but performing `HEAD` requests to hundreds of URLs in a row seems very inefficient!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API does not support getting the file size.

Comment: So how does the Sony PlayMemories app know what the size of the file is? During transfers a progress bar _is_ shown and for video it seems to actually be based on the file size.